# golang http net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x05\x00"

Tags: http, go, request, gorequest

When I use golang's net/http package to request different web pages, I often get this error, because of what?
(I used a proxy to crawl)

Comment: Care to share any code that would reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you connecting to a https server with http by any chance?

Comment: In these [two](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39506) [cases](https://forum.rclone.org/t/failed-to-configure-token/5301) I was able [to google](https://www.google.com/search?q=malformed+HTTP+response+“%5Cx05%5Cx00”), both hint at that a HTTP proxy is used. Is this indeed the case?